# Get data from IEnumerable using IEnumerable<string> as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a class of type

```
public class One
{
    public string firstString { get; set; }
    public string secondString { get; set; }
}
```

And IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<One> firstIEnumerable;
```

During program execution I get another IEnumerable,

```
IEnumerable<string> secondIEnumerable = List<string>.Where(...);
```

What I want is to request `firstIEnumerable`'s `secondString` using equality between `firstIEnumerable`'s `firstString` member and any value from `secondIEnumerable`.

I imagine a command like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> thirdIEnumerable =
    firstIEnumerable.Where(m=>m.firstString == secondIEnumerable.? ? ? ? ?).secondString;
```

But it doesn't compile.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to achieve without a concrete example. Please post a [mcve] with sample input and the output you're trying to achieve. Bear in mind that both are *sequences* - are you trying to match *each* item against another?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more direct and legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second enumerable is a long sequence you are probably (benchmark to check) better off doing two passes and creating a hash-set, rather than doing the O(N * M) algorithm. The O(N * M) one would be:

```
first.Where(x => second.Contains(x.firstString)).Select(x => x.secondString)
```

Using a hash set:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(second);
first.Where(x => hashSet.Contains(x.firstString)).Select(x => x.secondString)
```

The second option is likely to provide much better performance in most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to **select** the `secondString` for each item that its `firstString` is **contained** in `secondIEnumerable`:

```
var result = firstIEnumerable.Where(item => secondIEnumerable.Contains(item.firstString))
                             .Select(item => item.secondString);
```

Maybe nicer in query syntax:

```
var result = from item in firstIEnumerable
             where secondIEnumerable.Contains(item.firstString)
             select item.secondString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this:

```
        IEnumerable<string> thirdEnumerable =   from firstItem in firstIEnumerable
                                                from secondItem in secondIEnumerable
                                                where firstItem.firstString == secondItem
                                                select firstItem.firstString;
```

Or this inline way:

```
IEnumerable<string> thirdEnumerable2 = firstIEnumerable.Select(x => x.firstString).Intersect(secondIEnumerable);
```